# model set to be fixed to world keeps jittering

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

**Background**:
I want to set one of the box object to be fixed to the world.

**What I have tried**:

if an object set to be fixed to the world, it will keeps jittering. According to my search, some say it could be [inertia problem](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1363/gazebo-model-jittering/). Though I change it according to [formula of uniform 3d object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia), and it still doesn't work

**Source code**:

Here is the [wall.xacro](https://github.com/Shawnnn/ros/blob/master/wall.xacro) // script I show has commented the below code

Code below used to make box object fixed to world.

```
<!-- wall fixed to the world-->
    <link name="world"/>
    
    <joint name="base_link_fixed" type="fixed">
      <parent link="world"/>
      <child link="wall_link"/>
    </joint>
```

**Problem**:

However, the box turns out to be jittering all the time like dancing!!
[image: box_jitter]

**Solution Found**

Thank WarwickWagon's answer. The first solution works well.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16419/model-set-to-be-fixed-to-world-keeps-jittering/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2863/shawnysh/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There are two solutions:

1. Add the static tag to your model

   `<static>1</static>`
2. Add a valid inertial block to your model including correct mass and inertia matrix.

---

Originally posted by [WarwickWagon](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2385/warwickwagon/) with karma: 11 on 2017-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2863/shawnysh/) on 2017-06-13**:
Thank you WarwickWagon for your helpful and prompt reply! The first solution works for me perfectly. Actually I have tried the second solution which failed, as my update question shows. Thanks again.